# Chromium: missing sass support

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I tried to enable support for sass source mapping in Chromium (v31.0.1606.0) but it seems that there is the "Support for SASS"-option missing in my case.

I followed those instructions:
http://fonicmonkey.net/2013/03/25/native-sass-scss-source-map-support-in-chrome-and-rails/

Screenshot of my "Experiments"-Window:
see https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhFNp.png

Hint: I also tried it with Google Chrome Canary and Chrome v30 and it didn´t worked either.

Answer (score 5):

This one got me too, after reading a NetTuts article on Developing With Sass and Chrome DevTools. Seems like most articles on the subject are outdated.

Turns out **Chrome v30 and later ship with souce maps and SASS support enabled** by defualt. In v29 and earlier you have to check the "Support for SASS" box.

Furthermore, according to Google:
"Currently Sass is the only preprocessor that supports CSS source maps..."

So as long as you don't uncheck "Enable CSS Source Maps" in Dev Tools > Settings > General, you can hack away at your scss/sass directly from chrome.

I followed the Google Dev Tools docs and got it working on OSX.8 with Canary 32.0.1664.3. Here are the key points:

1. Make sure you're using sass 3.3.0alpha
   `gem install sass -v '>=3.3.0alpha' --pre`
2. Add the `--sourcemap` flag when you run sass from shell
   `sass --watch --sourcemap sass/styles.scss:styles.css`
3. Optionally enable "Auto-reload generated CSS" in Dev Tools > Settings > General for real-time goodness.

Here's a screenshot from my machine immediately after following the above steps and firing up a site with Sass.

[image: Debugging Sass in Chrome Dev Tools]

Sources:

[Working with CSS Preprocessors - Chrome DevTools – Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors)

[Developing With Sass and Chrome DevTools | Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/)